# how to use batch in c++

Tags: c++, batch-processing

I have a batch program that I would like to add to one of my c++ programs. The batch program tests if a file exists and exits the script if it doesn't. I do not want to add any more libraries to my code. The problem that I have is that I am not sure how I am able to use batch in c++. I am able to figure everything else out on my own I just need to know this one thing.

Comment: If you just need to check if a file exists, you don't need a .bat script. You can do it directly from C++.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How would I do that? I thought fstream was used for looking for files.

Comment: Sure, so try to open a file (for reading) and see if it opens? Or [`std::filesystem::exists`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `system(" ")` command to use batch.

Answer (score 0):

***Assuming you are on Windows,***
you have two options available to run batch files on Windows from C/C++.

- You can use system (or _wsystem for wide characters).

> "The [system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=msvc-170) function passes command to the command interpreter,
> which executes the string as an operating-system command. system
> refers to the COMSPEC and PATH environment variables that locate the
> command-interpreter file (the file named CMD.EXE in Windows 2000 and
> later)."

Or

- You can use [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) directly.

Note that for batch files:

> "To run a batch file, you must start the command interpreter; set
> lpApplicationName to cmd.exe and set lpCommandLine to the following
> arguments: /c plus the name of the batch file."